# Match node of called template

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

lets say I have a random template in my xsl:

```
<xsl:template name="keywords">
    <test>
        <foo>bar</foo>
        <bar>foo</bar>
    </test>
    <test>
        <foo>foobar</foo>
        <bar>barfoo</bar>
    </test>
<xsl:template>
```

I want to output let's say only the first node set. Is there an elegant way to do this?
How can I match the node if it is not in the source xml, but the result of a called template?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to store static nodes in a template, rather than in a variable or in an external document?

Comment: the original nodes are not static, this is just an example

Comment: I am afraid I cannot imagine a scenario where this would be useful. I suspect this is an XY question. What is your real purpose here?

Comment: I have a quite large template I am using elsewhere in my stylesheet. In another part of my document I want to put in a few nodes of it without unnecessarily repeating code

Comment: IMHO, you should do it the other way round: put the repeating part in a variable all on its own, and use it twice: once in the large template and once where you need it alone.

Comment: Thats a good point, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save the result of calling the template in a variable then you can extract parts of it using XPath

```
<xsl:variable name="result">
  <xsl:call-template name="keywords"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:sequence select="$keywords/test[1]" />
```

Comment: It's possible to address the template's nodes directly, even without using an interim variable - but it is awkward.

Comment: Thanks, this is already useable. @michael.hor257k what would be your awkward solution though?

Comment: You can also, of course, apply templates to the nodes in the variable. It's a standard technique, sometimes called micro-pipelining.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the nodes inside a named template using an Xpath expression like:

```
document('')/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:template[@name='keywords']/test[1]
```

---

**Added**:

For example, the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:template[@name='keywords']/test[1]"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="keywords">
    <test>
        <foo>bar</foo>
        <bar>foo</bar>
    </test>
    <test>
        <foo>foobar</foo>
        <bar>barfoo</bar>
    </test>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to *any* well-formed XML input, will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <test xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <foo>bar</foo>
      <bar>foo</bar>
   </test>
</output>
```

Note: you can get rid of the (harmless) redundant namespace declaration by applying templates instead of deep-copying.

Comment: this gives me a strange error: "Exception thrown by URIResolver" ... "String index out of range: -1". Ever seen this before?

Comment: What's your testing environment?

Comment: It is a Saxon processor

Comment: I don't know; it works for me with both Saxon 6.5 and Saxon 8.9. Are you passing an actual XSLT **file**?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. But anyway, thanks a lot for your patience and help. Would you mind posting your xml + xsl and I would figure out later where mine goes worng?